# EmberJS: Has no method lastObject, nextObject

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i was wondering how to call lastObject, nextObject on my Model/Store? I always get a 'Has no method'-Error.

Both methods are defined here:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  displayName: DS.attr('string')

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'

App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  init: ->
    console.info "last", App.Photo.lastObject
    console.info "next", App.Photo.nextObject(@get('content'))
```

**Update/Working Solution**

```
console.info "last", App.Photo.find().get('lastObject')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.Photo is not an array. It's a class.

App.Photo.find() will return an array-like object, a record array of all photos in the store, which will have a lastObject property, but you won't be able to call it like a function. Furthermore, #nextObject is overridden on arrays to be equivalent to #objectAt, so that won't work either (it doesn't work 'like that' either way, actually).

Comment: But I still don't how to get the #nextObject

Comment: x.objectAt(x.indexOf(this.get('content')) + 1)